# d3js - How to make animation to the nested arcs?

Tags: animation, d3.js

I have a requirement from my client to create multiple arcs. i find a solution for that. But still i don't know how to add the animation to the `pies`.

any one help me?

here is the code :

```
var dataset = {
  apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  oranges: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  lemons: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  pears: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  pineapples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    cwidth = 25;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return pie(d); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(10+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1))(d); });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/154/)

But how do add the animations to each of the pies?

Answer (score -1):

You are overwriting the `arc` `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` every time you do this:

```
.attr("d", function(d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(10+cwidth*j).outerRadius(cwidth*(j+1))(d); })
```

So, when you call `tweenPie` at the end, it's using whatever final state your `arc` is in. You can see this more clearly by adding a delay before the transition

```
.transition()
.delay(1000) // add this
.duration(3000)
.attrTween('d', tweenPie);
```

So, either define a different `arc` for each row of values or reset the arc inner/outer radius in your tweenPie call to match whichever row of data you're drawing.

Comment: you are mis understands my requirement. please visit my fiddle and remove the line what i noted and see the result. you will get multiple pies. i need to animate all pies each one by one

Comment: My point is that you are overwriting your `arc` function so only the final values for `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` are used. If you do an inspect element on your final donut chart, you'll see that it's drawing all three on top of each other.

Comment: You need to edit the arc function in `tweenPie` so it uses the correct radius.

Comment: can you see my updated question and help me to add the animation